# Debugging with PyCharm. Running script first

Tags: python, bash, pycharm

I am trying to debug my tests with PyCharm but I am currently getting this error:

```
pydev debugger: process 2386 is connecting

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 2222, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1648, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc) 
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 116, in <module>
    modules = [loadSource(a[0])]
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pycharm/utrunner.py", line 40, in loadSource
    module = imp.load_source(moduleName, fileName)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/imp.py", line 171, in load_source
    module = methods.load()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1220, in load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Trinity/qa-trinity/python_lib/qe/tests/test_web_events.py", line 21, in <module>
    import qe.util.scratchstore as scratchstore
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_pluginbase.py", line 452, in plugin_import
    fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_pluginbase.py", line 452, in plugin_import
    fromlist, level)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_pluginbase.py", line 452, in plugin_import
    fromlist, level)
ImportError: No module named 'qe'
```

Normally in the terminal, I run this script before my tests:

```
$ source ../setup.sh
```

contents of setup.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $_ != $0 ]] && this_is_sourced=1 || this_is_sourced=""
this_script_path="${BASH_SOURCE[@]}"
if [[ ${this_is_sourced} ]]; then
    pushd $(dirname ${this_script_path}) >/dev/null
    this_script_dir=$(pwd)
    this_script_pkgs=$(echo qe/[a-z]*[a-z0-9] | sed 's%qe/%%g')
    popd >/dev/null
    #### set environment vars
    export PYTHONPATH="$this_script_dir"
    export PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE="1"
    /usr/bin/env | grep -Fe "PYTHON" >/dev/tty
    export PATH="/trinityqa00/opt/bin:/qa00/opt/bin:/home/sthe/opt/bin:${PATH}"
    for pkg in $this_script_pkgs; do
        export PATH="${PYTHONPATH}/qe/${pkg}:${PATH}"
    done
    echo "PATH=${PATH}" >/dev/tty
    ####
    unset this_script_dir
    unset this_script_path
    unset this_is_sourced
else
    echo "usage: source ${this_script_path}"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: In your run configuration, there is a 'Before launch' section where you can add tasks to be run before the launch of the program - I'm not sure if this runs in the same environment as the script, but it seems likely - might be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Didnt work though =/ And I'm not sure why. I added the script to `Before launch`. I am getting `/Users/bli1/Development/Trinity/qa-trinity/python_lib/setup.sh
/Users/bli1/Development/Trinity/qa-trinity/python_lib/setup.sh: line 12: /dev/tty: Device not configured
/Users/bli1/Development/Trinity/qa-trinity/python_lib/setup.sh: line 17: /dev/tty: Device not configured` Not really sure what that means. This script isn't mine. I am copying a proj right now

Comment: Sounds like it's looking for an interactive terminal, which Pycharm isn't giving it (presumably a pipe to Pycharm). Don't know a way around that one, I'm afraid.

Comment: Where is the qe module actually located? As far as I can see, source.sh mostly adds directories to PATH, which shouldn't affect Python imports.

Comment: @yole I am in the directory `rundata` and `qe` is located `..` from the directory I am trying to run the script in.

Comment: What is the content root of the project in PyCharm?

Comment: @yole the project is located `~/Development/Trinity/qa-trinity` Path to `rundata` is `~/Development/Trinity/qa-trinity/python_lib/rundata`